# Is my code part of the view, model or controller?

Tags: java, javafx

I have am confronted with the following points which kind of confuse me in regards to implementing MVC:

**Scenario 1:** Searching for nodes and children and storing those in variables making them accessible later with getters. I also store the stage and scene there. Would a scenerio like that fit in the model?

```
 root = primaryStage;
 node 1= (VBox) root.lookup("#node1");
 node 2 = (VBox) root.lookup("#node2");
 node 3 = (VBox) root.lookup("#node3");

private void getPrimaryStage() {
   return root;
}
```

**Scenario 2:** I have my view and logic seperate. Nearly all my gui elements are in an fxml file. However what if I want to create a node and add it dynamically?

**Scenario 3:** What about code that changes how the existing view works? Is this the work of the controller?

```
node.setMaxWidth((scene.getWidth() / 2 - 100);


private void position() {
    nodeA.setTranslateX(-300);
    nodeB.setTranslateX(-300);

    nodeA.setTranslateX(40);
    nodeB.setTranslateY((scene / 2 - nodeB.getHeight()) / 8);
    nodeC.setTranslateY((scene / 2 - nodeB.getHeight()) / 8);
}
```

Comment: Have you actually [researched](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/basic_mvc_architecture.htm) into the MVC architecture yet?

Comment: @px06 trust me I really did read many resources and practiced

Comment: please consider marking answer as correct, if that is per your expectation.

Comment: @prabodhprakash accepted, you might want to check out my updated question though. Could you just commented to the example I posted? Its a more detailed code so you know what I mean.

Comment: Scenario 3: This can go in view. This is purely view manipulation and no issues, if it goes there.

Comment: @prabodhprakash wow thanks. I was just confused since calculations are "logic" and well I thought those come in the model. That was the most confusing part.

Comment: No, models, in general take care of biggies - like DB, networking, custom business logic (like total payable amount calculation etc) - these are little stuffs and scenario 3, in particular, deals only with UI placement logic - view should be okay place for this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will tell you a generic concept.

Model holds your business logic <--> Controller passes data <--> view shows it.

**Scenario 1**: Searching for nodes and children and storing those in variables making them accessible later with getters. I also store the stage and scene there. Would a scenerio like that fit in the model?

Yes, as per this description, it looks to be a good fit for model.

**Scenario 2**: I have my view and logic seperate. Nearly all my gui elements are in an fxml file. However what if I want to create a node and add it dynamically?

How is the node created? If there is some complex logic, it should be done in model, controller then should pass on the cooked data to view, which can simply fit in these data and render new node.

Comment: What they do was clear to me but its sometimes hard since the interfaces often come somewhat mixed it seems. The node is created by instantiating a new object, such as: Button button = new Button("test"). Then I append it on existing nodes

Comment: However, what about width calculations etc that happen later such as node.setMaxWidth((scene.getWidth() / 2 - 100); Some functions are build solely for computing the width and adding it onto the views nodes.

Comment: See, as a general rule - you can do simple stuffs in controller. Make sure, nothing major is happening in view, it should just be used to display, and transfer user actions. Model should be for heavy business logic, DB operations, network operations etc. You can do setMaxWidth in controller, should be okay.

Comment: All UI things should be done in the View, so setting some sort of a UI size or doing anything that is to do with UI should be done in View. Everything else is fine; i.e. Business logic should really be in the Model, the controller should handle other logic that isn't very heavy and view is just a means of display.

Comment: @px06 but if view is just for display, do all the gui changes such as changing and simple recalculations of the gui go there? I mean some logic is happening there. Check my question, just edited it

Comment: @Asperger You calculations are done in the controller and sent to the view, think of the Model/Controller as an API. It feels you information that you implement. All processing should be done in the Controller and model.